# .net console project returns type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager' in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm working on a .NET  C# console application that I want to connect to a mysql database, the app does a row count and checks the status of a message field and then deletes records with message status done or failed. when I run the application it returns The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager' threw an exception.

The app references MySql.Data.MySqlClient to connect to a MySQL 8.29 server
the nugget version for MySql.Data is 8.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to nugget package manager in visual studio and uninstall the current nugget for MySql.Data.

Then open the PM console from Tools, NuGet Package Manager then select Package Manager Console

in the Console type NuGet\Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.10.7

using version 6.10.7 resolved the error

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people